# Translating Matriz in GLSL won't work with variables

Tags: opengl, glsl

So... i made this mat4 matriz which would translate a triangle according to the coordinates. I realized that with the following matriz, the triangle would translate to the right of the screen:

```
Camera[0] = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
Camera[1] = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
Camera[2] = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
Camera[3] = vec4(0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

Now, i read that a translating matriz in GLSL would look like this:

```
Camera[0] = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
Camera[1] = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
Camera[2] = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
Camera[3] = vec4(X, Y, Z, 1.0);
```

So therefore, i created a variable, which would contain these 3 values.

```
layout(location = 2) in vec3 CAM;
```

And i would do the following to establish the values in the corresponding places:

```
Camera[0] = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
Camera[1] = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
Camera[2] = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
Camera[3] = vec4(CAM.x, CAM.y, CAM.z, 1.0);
```

I thought that if CAM.x = 0.5 And CAM.y = 0.0, CAM.z = 0.0, i would have the same result as i had when i established manually X to be 0.5, and both Y and Z to be 0.0, since those are precisely the values of CAM. But rather, i got completely different results.

```
Camera[0] = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
Camera[1] = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
Camera[2] = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
Camera[3] = vec4(0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

Gives me the following result: [image]

And

```
    Camera[0] = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    Camera[1] = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    Camera[2] = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    Camera[3] = vec4(CAM.x, CAM.y, CAM.z, 1.0);
```

gave me the following result:[image]

Even though CAM.x = 0.5; CAM.y = 0.0; CAM.z = 0.0. (I checked it myself inside the vertex Shader by changing the red color of one of the vertices if the values of CAM were correct. By adding the following code: `if(CAM.x == 0.5) ColorValue.x = 0.0;` I got the following result: [image]). How can this be??

This is the whole Vertex Code by the way:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 VertexPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 COR;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 CAM;
out vec3 ColorValue;

void main(){

    mat4 Camera;
    Camera[0] = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    Camera[1] = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    Camera[2] = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    Camera[3] = vec4(CAM.x, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    vec4 point = vec4(VertexPosition.x, VertexPosition.y, VertexPosition.z, 1.0);
    vec4 Transformed_Point = Camera * point;

    gl_Position = Transformed_Point;

    ColorValue.xyz = COR.xyz;



}
```

Comment: I feel like a dumbass. I have been trying to understand what is going on for like 30 minutes. This is driving me insane.

Comment: Change the vertex color to be CAM.X, Y and Z for RGB. It should be a dark red color `0x800000`, see what you get.

Comment: http://i.gyazo.com/6c8a4b4feba8ed295c4b879f2fbcc05e.png  This. CAM.x is 0.5, Y and Z are 0, as it shows in the colors. But anyway, the triangle still hasnt shifted to the right the way it was supposed to.

Comment: That seems to confirm Nico's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are handling the camera position as a vertex attribute. That's why the first vertex is correctly shifted but the other two are at their original positions (because their camera attribute is zero). Use a uniform instead.

Comment: God... Thank you so, so much!